# Statistical and systematics uncertainties with siunitx

Tags: errors, siunitx

I am writing a paper and need to include statistical and systematic errors with units. Using siunitx I would like to be able to do the following (for example)

```
\SI{1 \pm 0.3 (sys) \pm 0.1 (stat)}{\meter}
```

But when I do I get the following errors

```
siunitx error: "misplaced-sign-token"

Misplaced sign token '\pm'
```

For having multiple `\pm` (without text) and I get

```
siunitx error: "invalid-token-in-uncertainty"

Invalid uncertainty in numerical input '1 \pm 0.3 (sys)'.
```

If I get rid of the stat error.

I guess a minimal example would be

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\sisetup{separate-uncertainty=true}
\begin{document}
  \SI{1 \pm 0.3 (sys) \pm 0.1 (stat)}{\meter}
\end{document}
```

Thanks in advance for the help

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Are you perhaps after `parse-numbers=false`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\sisetup{separate-uncertainty=true}
\begin{document}
  \SI[parse-numbers=false]{1 \pm 0.3 (sys) \pm 0.1 (stat)}{\meter}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

In the meantime, there have been updates to `siunitx`, such that the following syntax works:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\sisetup{separate-uncertainty=true,separate-uncertainty-units=single}
\begin{document}
$m_H=\qty[uncertainty-descriptors={stat,sys}]{125.22(11)(9)}{\GeV}$
\end{document}
```

[image: the rendered text, i.e. the Higgs mass with uncertainties]

More can be found in the [documentation](https://texdoc.org/serve/siunitx/0) or in [this Github issue](https://github.com/josephwright/siunitx/issues/24#issuecomment-1086844403).